# lines are not being drawn on overlay view

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, cgcontext, mkoverlay

I am trying to draw a straight line between two points in overlay view.
In MKOverlayView method, I think I am doing correctly but I don't understand why it's not drawing any lines...

Does anyone know why?

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    MKMapRect theMapRect = [[self overlay] boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    // Clip the context to the bounding rectangle.
    CGContextAddRect(context, theRect);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGPoint startP = {theMapRect.origin.x, theMapRect.origin.y};
    CGPoint endP = {theMapRect.origin.x + theMapRect.size.width,
        theMapRect.origin.y + theMapRect.size.height};

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startP.x, startP.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endP.x, endP.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line is being drawn using `startP` and `endP` which are `CGPoint` values but they are initialized using `theMapRect` which contains `MKMapPoint` values.

Instead, initialize them using `theRect` which you are converting from `theMapRect` using `rectForMapRect`.

Also, for the line width, you may want to scale it using the `MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale` function.  Otherwise, a fixed line width of `3.0` will not be visible unless you are zoomed in very close.

The changed code would look like this:

```
CGPoint startP = {theRect.origin.x, theRect.origin.y};
CGPoint endP = {theRect.origin.x + theRect.size.width,
    theRect.origin.y + theRect.size.height};

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0 * MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale));
```

Finally, instead of a custom `MKOverlayView`, why not use a `MKPolylineView` to avoid drawing lines manually?

Comment: Hi, I have one more question... If I am to initialize CGPoint from boundingMapRect, how should I do????

Comment: oh.. and the reason I am not using MkPolylineView is I need to draw an arrow not just straight line....

Comment: Not sure what "initialize CGPoint from boundingMapRect" means.  Isn't that what you're already doing?  What kind of backing MKOverlay are you using -- custom or something like MKPolyline/MKPolygon?  ie. What kind of class is `[self overlay]`?  Not sure why you would use the boundingMapRect to construct the lines anyway.  The MKOverlay should define the location/orientation of the arrow and the view should draw it.  Eg. If the overlay contains coordinates, you could convert them to MKMapPoints using `MKMapPointForCoordinate` and then to a CGPoint using `pointForMapPoint:`.

Comment: Another alternative is to create an MKPolygon that has the exact outline of the arrow (calculated with either MKMapPoints or CLLocationCoordinate2Ds) and create a MKPolygonView for it (no custom classes or drawing needed).  Another alternative (if you want the arrow to remain a constant size regardless of zoom) is to use an annotation instead of an overlay and use an arrow image.

Comment: The code above is just for testing to see if I can draw custom lines on the map. They don't have any special purposes. But I didn't know that MKPolygonView can do arrow shape.... Thank you very much for your help!